# How to pass parameters as TEXT in mediawiki

Tags: php, mediawiki

I was using syntaxhighlight plugin for rendering my code.
I design a template for it and afer that I create a form base on it.
The template is this, where I just want to pass parameters code and type:

```
{{#tag:syntaxhighlight|{{{code|}}}|lang={{{type|cpp}}}|}}
```

The problem is that when code contains the pipe symbol ('|') things will go wrong.
I'm seeking any way to making code a pure text variable to make it work.

Comment: When you invoke a template from wikitest, you could replace all `|` with `{{!}}`. PageForms is a different matter.

Comment: Short answer is you can't do that with templates, you'll need to escape |, =, {{ etc. I have seen some hack with Lua where you can insert all the code inside <nowiki> tags and Lua would strip the <nowiki> out, but if you do this then you can as well use the <syntaxhighlight> tag directly.

Comment: So maybe I should use <syntaxhighlight> directly instead of {{#tag}}